# What is the best way to mix+master a snare so that it sounds good on different devices?

Tags: mixing, mixer, mastering

I am working on a song (multiple, actually) that sounds alright, except for the snare.

The snare is very prominent on phones, as it takes up the higher regions of the audio spectrum, and can tend to drown out the other instruments. On my computer, I made the volume of the snare just right, so it isn't too prominent, but when I play it on my phone, it is much louder, as phones tend to play the higher end of the audio spectrum louder (at least, that's my experience).

However, when I lower the volume of the snare for it to sound better on phones, it becomes too quiet on the computer. What do you recommend I do so that it sounds good on multiple devices?

Comment: You could just be EQing it too bright, but without a snippet to listen to it's almost impossible to guess.

Comment: @Tetsujin There is no EQ on the snare, but boosting the low-end would take the punch out of it

Comment: Then the mic placement may be wrong. Without hearing it, really, no-one can guess.

Comment: Its electronic. I'll see about uploading the song

Comment: How can you compare oranges to apples... I don't get it, how can the proportions of something be kept intact when the difference is as colossal as a phone "speaker" and a PC speaker? ...

Comment: @frcake well im asking for a good balance

Comment: Find your reference system and mix there, the final product will be judged by how good the reference system translates to other systems. Achieving a good and balanced mix that translates is an art itself and not a simple task of just moving the fader on a snare.. You can make small adjustments if something is really off in other systems, but you have to have your reference/mixing point where it all begins. After a long time you will have a better understanding on what you have to do beforhand in order to achieve a mix that translates (again it all connects to your mixing system - speaker/room)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general problem with every audio file - it will sound different on every system you play it.

The solution - when creating your mix, you need to play it on a wide range of outputs to see how it sounds, and decide on a final balance that works "best" across the media you care about. That may be for car audio with it's enclosed space providing overwhelming bass, or for mobile phone speakers, which are tinny, etc., not just for your flat spectrum Genelec monitors in the studio.

And it is an art - one that is incredibly subjective.

Comment: Anecdotally, I could never get a portable mix on Gennies, I had the [1032A](https://www.genelec.com/previous-models/1032a). I eventually swapped them for [DynAudio BM6A](https://www.dynaudio.com/professional-audio/classic-bm-range/bm6a) & never looked back ;)

Comment: Yeah - always too bland on Genelecs. I agree.